# Unexpected Error Local path doesn't exist in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

While running my application in **Android-Studio** I got an **Exception** and cant find out the cause of the problem,

[image: like]

My application is related to **read** a data from **Excel** which has **.xls** and **.xlsx** format.

So I used **poi-3.9.jar** for **.xls**-

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

And **poi-ooxml-3.9.jar** for **.xlsx**-

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

And my **build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "packagename"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/poi-3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
}
```

while running ./gradlew assembleDebug got an error as,

```
:app:preBuild                                                                    
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE     
:app:preDebugBuild                
:app:checkDebugManifest                 
:app:preReleaseBuild                 
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE      
:app:prepareDebugDependencies                 
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE      
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE      
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE      
:app:preDexDebug                 

trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.                        

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

1 error; aborting                
:app:preDexDebug FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        /Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --output /AndroidStudioProjects/MobileBoard/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/stax-api-1.0.1-5ca3434ead959ccca3873db7fc4de10e3c95b844.jar /AndroidStudioProjects/MobileBoard/app/libs/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
  Error Code: 
        1     
  Output:     

        trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":

        Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
        when not building a core library.

        This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
        in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
        Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
        core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
        going on.

        However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
        namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
        from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
        assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
        compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
        It is also often of questionable legality.

        If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
        appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
        distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
        the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

        If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
        building an application, then be forewarned that your application
        will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
        prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
        application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
        system. You will be to blame for this problem.

        If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
        core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
        repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
        your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
        conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
        you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
        that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
        lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

        1 error; aborting


* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 59.412 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: use terminal in android studio and try to run command gradlew assembleDebug and post what you get in results here.

Comment: @pyus13 I edit my question by result of gradle assembleDebug. Please check it out

Comment: try to add this in your build.gradle file `configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'stax'
    compile.exclude group: 'xpp3'
}`

Comment: It is because your xmlbeans jar is creating problem it has some dependencies which android doesn't like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans260jar.htm

Comment: In which attribute I want to add configurations { compile.exclude group: 'stax' compile.exclude group: 'xpp3' }

Comment: @pyus13 compile.exclude cannot resolved compile inside dependencies

Comment: add it on root level like dependencies block, not inside anything and try.

Comment: @pyus13 still has the error :(